# Azure App Service Oauth failure after Mobile Service migration

Tags: google-oauth, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services

Up to this point, I had a functioning Azure Mobile Service with service-directed OAuth working nicely for Google.  I tried to rehost the mobile service as an app service since mobile services are deprecated.  I also have an HTML/JS web app that accesses my service through the `MobileServiceClient` JS client.  This is where the fun starts.

After changing the redirect address to the appropriate app service address in the Google API manager, I get a message saying I'm successfully logged in in a new popup window: [image: a].

Clicking on "Return to Website" takes me to the address of my app service, not the app that initiated the OAuth request, and if I close this window, the `MobileServiceClient` throws a "cancelled" exception and I don't get my credentials.

What am I missing or what changed that I need to account for?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this particular behavior happens when using an older version of the `MobileServiceClient` JS library.  Replacing the 1.2.7 version with the 2.0.0beta version fixed this.  To get the whole OAuth flow working, I also needed to add the appropriate addresses to the allowedExternalRedirectUrls node of the config/authsettings node through the Azure Resource Explorer.  If there is a nicer way to do it than through the resource explorer, I don't know what it is.